# We like to wish you .. VS We would like to wish you...

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm having some difficulty with this sentence. 
Can one say: ''We like''...(to wish, to ask, to join etc)

In my opinion one can never say ''we like to'' but must always say ''We WOULD like to'' or ''we'd like to''.

Not a native speaker, help me out :)

Comment: "We like to" might be said by a non-native speaker who has heard "We'd like to", but didn't notice the "'d"

Answer (score 1):

> "We like to X"

implies

> "We enjoy doing X", *or*
>
> "We habitually do X" (e.g. "We like to water-ski").

---

> "We would like to X"

implies

> "We want to do X".

Comment: So if you want to say: We(would) like to wish you a Merry Christmas. What is better? ''We would like to wish you a merry Christmas!'' OR ''We like to wish you a merry Christmas''

Comment: @Celine - The standard formula in this case is "We wish you a merry Christmas". "We would like to wish you a merry Christmas!" sounds OK, if a little tentative; "We like to wish you a merry Christmas" would sound wrong (i.e. unidiomatic) to a native speaker.

Comment: A popular bilingual song comes to mind. "I want to wish you a merry Christmas!"